# 'x' is not numeric in R. Rejection sampling in R

Tags: r, numeric

```
rexp_k <- function(a,b) {
  y <- runif(1)
  u <- runif(1)
  a <- 2.5
  b <- 3.5
  f <- (y^(a-1))*((1-y)^(b-1))
  g <- dunif(y)
  M <- ((a-1)/(a+b-2))^(a-1)*(1-((a-1)/(a+b-2)))^(b-1)
  if (M*u <= f/g) {
    return (y)
  }
}

a <- 2.5
b <- 3.5

beta_samples <- replicate(10, rexp_k(a,b))    
hist(beta_samples, probability = T)
```

So it gives me an error saying that x is not numeric when i try plotting the histogram in the last line.
i am trying to do rejection sampling in R.

Comment: Maybe you want `hist(unlist(beta_samples), probability = T)`? Because `beta_samples` is a list because your function doesn't always return a vector so NULLs are included in the output. Not sure exactly what behavior you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your example gives a list output.
This is what the standard output of `replicate()` is.

You get `NULL` values because your function doesn't always return a value.

Since you only return numeric and NULL values, and since you need to `unlist()` anyway, you can just use `unlist()` and that's it.

```
> beta_samples
[[1]]
[1] 0.2615192

[[2]]
[1] 0.5856312

[[3]]
[1] 0.4794066

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
[1] 0.3697637

[[6]]
NULL

[[7]]
[1] 0.5003103

[[8]]
NULL

[[9]]
NULL

[[10]]
NULL
```

After `unlist()` the NULL values in lists are removed.
This wouldn't be the case if they were `NA` or character values but for you it'll do the trick.

```
> unlist(beta_samples)
[1] 0.2615192 0.5856312 0.4794066 0.3697637 0.5003103
```

And you can plot your histogram with these.

```
hist(unlist(beta_samples), probability = T)
```

[image: Histogram output]